# correct declaration of function in the code snippet below

Tags: c++, boost

What is the correct way of writing these functions get_m_source() , get_m_key() and get_m_data()
I tried the first approach below since what was being returned is a boost::optional.
But it resulted in an error as shown below -

```
/home/badri/sandboxes_git/acvs-illustra-global/output/amb_cv22_evk/arm/release/usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::construct(boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::argument_type) [with T = tev::events::EventItemCategory; boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::argument_type = const tev::events::EventItemCategory&]’:
/home/badri/sandboxes_git/acvs-illustra-global/output/amb_cv22_evk/arm/release/usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:181:18:   required from ‘boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::optional_base(const boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>&) [with T = tev::events::EventItemCategory]’
/home/badri/sandboxes_git/acvs-illustra-global/output/amb_cv22_evk/arm/release/usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:944:5:   required from here
/home/badri/sandboxes_git/acvs-illustra-global/output/amb_cv22_evk/arm/release/usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:384:8: error: use of deleted function ‘tev::events::EventItemCategory::EventItemCategory(const tev::events::EventItemCategory&)’
  384 |        ::new (m_storage.address()) value_type(val) ;
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

```
class EventMessage
{
public:
    .
    .
    boost::optional<EventItemCategory> get_m_source() { return m_source; }
    boost::optional<EventItemCategory> get_m_key() { return m_key; }
    boost::optional<EventItemCategory> get_m_data() { return m_data; }

private:
    void                                                                           init();
    boost::optional<EventItemCategory>&            getEventItemCategory( EVENT_ITEM_CATEGORY_TYPE const& type );

    time_t m_timestamp;
    boost::optional<PROPERTY_OPERATION> m_propertyOperation;
    boost::optional<EventItemCategory> m_source;
    boost::optional<EventItemCategory> m_key;
    boost::optional<EventItemCategory> m_data;
    std::map<EVENT_ITEM_CATEGORY_TYPE const, boost::optional<EventItemCategory> & > m_eventItemMap;
};
```

I tried the second approach knowing well that it isn't going to work. As expected, the error thrown was -

```
./EventMessage.hpp:68:47: error: could not convert ‘((tev::events::EventMessage*)this)->tev::events::EventMessage::m_source’ from ‘boost::optional<tev::events::EventItemCategory>’ to ‘tev::events::EventItemCategory’
```

```
class EventMessage
{
public:
    .
    .
    .
    EventItemCategory get_m_source() { return m_source; }
    EventItemCategory get_m_key() { return m_key; }
    EventItemCategory get_m_data() { return m_data; }


private:
    void                                                                           init();
    boost::optional<EventItemCategory>&            getEventItemCategory( EVENT_ITEM_CATEGORY_TYPE const& type );

    time_t m_timestamp;
    boost::optional<PROPERTY_OPERATION> m_propertyOperation;
    boost::optional<EventItemCategory> m_source;
    boost::optional<EventItemCategory> m_key;
    boost::optional<EventItemCategory> m_data;
    std::map<EVENT_ITEM_CATEGORY_TYPE const, boost::optional<EventItemCategory> & > m_eventItemMap;
};
```

Comment: I'm guessing `EventItemCategory` isn't copyable, please show a [mre]

Comment: Thanks Alan. I will get one.

Comment: Here's your starting point http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb9c0d08f87a541a. Just edit till it makes the error appear

Comment: With a MSVP, I got this extra note that makes your suspicion right, Alan.

EventItemCategory.hpp:66:7: note: ‘EventItemCategory::EventItemCategory(const EventItemCategory&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘EventItemCategory’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
 class EventItemCategory
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: so this  being the case, how can I perform something equivalent to 

boost::optional<EventItemCategory> get_m_source() { return m_source; }

I want to have a function such as get_m_source() so that I can access m_source for my debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the solution was to move it, since it was not copyable !
With this change, the MSVP compiled for me.

boost::optional get_m_source() { return std::move(m_source); }

Comment: That has the side effect of clearing `m_source`. That's weird for a member function named `getXXXXXX`

Comment: Guess what. I think I might have felt the side effect. There was a crash and it disappeared after I did my debugging and removed the call to get_m_source()

Comment: I had to check some  contents using the m_source. But EventItemCategory declares a move constructor and therefore uncopyable. If I had to get m_source, I could only move it again and return it ! Is there anything else I could have done to prevent the crash ? What to do if classes like EventItemCategory make it uncopyable.

Comment: If something is not copyable, and you do not wish to copy it, perhaps don't copy it. The most natural way is to return a reference?